# How to remove the browser cache in HTML which uses AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, browser-cache

How to remove the browser cache in HTML which uses AngularJS? I used the following in my index.html. I also tried using `$templateCache` in my app.js but no use.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />


app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider.when('/login',{templateUrl: '/partials/login.html',controller:'loginCtrl'});
        $routeProvider.when('/fingerprint',{templateUrl: '/partials/fingerprint.html',controller:'fingerprintCtrl',resolve: {
                            factory: checkRouting
                        }});
        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
        }]).
        run(function($templateCache) {
          $templateCache.removeAll();
        });

        var checkRouting= function ($q, $rootScope, $location,$http) {
            if ($rootScope.loggedUser) {
                return true;
            } else {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.post("#/fingerprint", { userToken: "blah" })
                    .success(function (response) {
                        $rootScope.loggedUser = response.loggedUser;
                        deferred.resolve(true);
                    })
                    .error(function () {
                        deferred.reject();
                        $location.path("/");
                     });
                return false;
            }
        };
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The browser cache is not getting removed automatically. The user have to manually remove it every time they login to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really stored in browser's cache then it has nothing to do with `$templateCache` because that is used by Angular to cache templates only.

Maybe check server's cache settings in headers for static `*.html`.

Btw, how do you manually remove cached page from browser? By dumping all temporary data?

Comment: May be I'm not clear with my question, let me put it this way. I need to do a force refresh every time I login to see the changes. Different users have different customised views which are called by the Angular partials. When I do a right click->Inspect Element and check in the Network tab, I can see that these partials are being cached. I don't want them to cached.

Comment: That's what thought. Do the `*.html` files return 304 status code which means they're cached? If so, have a look at server configuration or if you're rendering them by some backend script (eg. PHP) check what headers you set there (eg. `ETag`, `Last-Modified`, etc.) .

Comment: res.setHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache', 'no-store', 'must-revalidate'); should I be using this?

Comment: I have a logic in my directive which calls the partial corresponding to the user details. So when the user logins it show call the corresponding partial but since they are getting cached, it is displaying the previous partial only. Then how will setting the Last-modified tag affect?

Comment: You wrote that it's cache in the browser and you already use `$templateCache.removeAll()`. That's why.

Answer (score 0):

Add an anchor tag 'Clear Cache 'in the html href="javascript:location.reload(true)"